# How can i get wysiwyg editor for text field in shopware 6?

Tags: shopware

I want to change input-field type text into wysiwyg editor.how can i change this into wysiwyg editor?

```
    <input-field type="text">
        <name>PriceTextField</name>
        <label>Write  Text For Price</label>
        <defaultValue>Price</defaultValue>
    </input-field>
```